# Expresso Store, required address field based on country

Tags: expresso-store

It seems if I require the State of a billing or shipping field, it is required whether or not the selected country has "states". For example, if France is selected, the State dropdown has no options, but the user can't proceed because the State field is required.

What is the best way to correct this?

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify on checkout form opening `exp:store:checkout` what is required. Remove state from there and you should be good.

Comment: That's what I figured, but would this affect US or Canada products, if they forget to select State? I'm assuming the Zip being required would make this a non-issue, but I'm just trying to be thorough.

Comment: From what I have experienced it will effects when you will use UPS/Fedex shipping modules, but not when you will use shipping rules. Both modules use the State and ZIP code to calculate shipping.

Comment: Yeah I've tested and International shipping is not auto-selected in this instance. Have you found a workaround for this?

Comment: No. I think in that case you need to wait for Ian or Adrian to get direct response from Expresso dev team.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean "International shipping is not auto-selected in this instance"? Which shipping method are you using? Making state required/not required should not have any effect on shipping.

Comment: Adrian, thanks for the response. In this case, I mean the shipping method "International" is automatically selected when a foreign country with a State is used. When no State is selected, the default shipping option UPS Ground (not applicable to International orders) is selected and the price is $0.

Comment: Are you using the UPS extension, or custom shipping rules? UPS ground should not appear for international orders, regardless of the State. Perhaps you can post a new question with all the details? (and ideally a link to your site so we can see it in action).